# What PCI WiFi cards Work with 11.04?

Tags: wireless, hardware, compatibility, pci

I'm looking for a stable wifi card that will work with Ubuntu 11.04 64 bits without not too many steps to configure it correctly..just install and start up.

I found this [list](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported) but there isn't any reference to the Ubuntu release..

Regards

Javi

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, then please flag explaining that (as well as editing your question with any details you have).

Answer (score 2):

There are a few models listed in the [certified components catalog](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/category/WIRELESS).

Answer (score 0):

i can confirm that d-link works right out of the box, i have a d-link wifi card on my computer and it just worked without issue when i installed 11.04. which model? i am not sure but this is what the device manager shows "Atheros AR5001X+ Wireless Network Adapter"

Answer (score 0):

I bought myself a PCIE WLAN card a couple of weeks ago. Worked straight away. It's called D-Link DWA-556. I'm really happy with it. Drivers are built-in and no required configurations except providing the password for the network, of course.

Answer (score 0):

If the Linux kernel supports a particular wireless adapter then Ubuntu will support that wireless adapter. The latest Ubuntu will always have the latest Linux kernel and therefore have the most up to date support for any kind of device.

If a Ubuntu developer were to produce a driver module for a certain device, then that code would be passed upstream to the Linux kernel developers for inclusion in the kernel and then come back down stream when the modified kernel is used by Ubuntu. This is how the system works. In this way all Linux users would benefit.

You have answered your own question by making the link to the WiFi Docs Wireless Cards Supported page, which was updated in August of this year.

Regards.